# Elasticsearch - advanced filter

Tags: java, arrays, spring, elasticsearch

I have an array of below objects:

```
[{
   "id":1,
   "code":"00200"
},
{
   "id":2,
   "code":"00300"
}]
```

and I must return all objects from this array, but only this one when in below array my `code == code1` (`code` from first array is equal `code` from the second array) and `code2 = 'A'` (`code2` from the second array is equal `A`):

```
[{
    id: 1,
    code1: "00200",
    code2: "A"
},
{
    id: 1,
    code1: "00200",
    code2: "B"
}]
```

and I must do it via `ElasticSearch` and `BoolQueryBuilder`...

I tried to use a `filter` but without success because I do not know how to check if a value from one array is in a second array.

```java
BoolQueryBuilder boolQB;
boolQB.filter(QueryBuilders.must(...))
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Stream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method to check whether a value from one array is in a second array. For example, your code might look like this:

```java
Code[] codes = {new Code(1, "00200"), new Code(1, "00300")};
Code2[] codes2 = {new Code2(1, "00200", "A"), new Code2(1, "00200", "B")};

Arrays.stream(codes)
        .filter(code -> Arrays.stream(codes2)
                .anyMatch(code2 -> code.getCode().equals(code2.getCode1())))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
// Code{id=1, code='00200'}
```